# onclick javascript function not passing variable from textbox

Tags: javascript, function, variables, textbox, onclick

I've been digging through Stack Overflow for a few days now trying to figure out why my code isn't working. Alas, here I am, asking a very simple question.

I have an HTML form that has a text box and a submit button. You enter a number into the textbox, click the submit button and it's supposed to update a div with information about the number you entered. I know the function works. If I hard code a number into the submit button, it inserts the html properly. But if I change the submit button's onclick to include the text in the textbox, nothing happens.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML===============================

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="thenumber" id="thenumber" /> <input type="button" onClick="numbers(document.getElementById('thenumber').value);" value="Click Me!" />
</form>
<div id="message"></div>
```

JS=================================

```
var numbers = function(identify){

switch (identify) {

    case '1234':
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Device 1";
        break;
    case '5678':
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Device 2";
        break;
    case '9101':
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Device 3";
        break;
        default:
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Device Unknown";
};
};
```

Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a parenthesis

```
    "numbers(document.getElementById('thenumber').value)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I corrected that, but it's still not working. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Use all lowercase `onclick`?

Comment: The all lowercase onclick fixed it. I'm so confused. Dreamweaver automatically capitalizes the C! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want include the text in the text box, you don't have to use innerHTML, you have to use value.

Ex:document.getElementById("message").value = "Device Unknown";

Comment: The value in the text box is just to check if the device is in the list. For example, if "1234" was entered into the text box, "Device 1" would show up in the DIV.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try copy my code.

```
<input type="text" name="thenumber" id="thenumber" /> 
<input type="button" onClick="numbers(document.getElementById('thenumber').value)" value="Click Me!" />

<div id="message"></div>

var numbers = function(identify){

switch (identify) {

    case '1234':
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Device 1";
        break;
    case '5678':
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Device 2";
        break;
    case '9101':
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Device 3";
        break;
        default:
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Device Unknown";
};
};
```

You have a syntax error on onClick event